# file_get_contents ignoring verify_peer=>false?

Tags: php, ssl, https

file_get_contents with https hosts works just fine, except for a particular host (test api server from some company - ip whitelisted, can't give you URL to test). This rules out not loaded https modules and other initial setup mistakes.

I have tested with multiple PHP installations, all at v5.3.3, 32bits, Debian 32bits.

The request works with cURL, but only if setting `curl_setopt($curl, 
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);`. However, setting `verify_peer"=>false` on the context for file_get_contents seems to make no difference.

With file_get_contents, the exact same request (same URL, same XML POST data) fails with **SSL: Connection reset by peer**:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => 
            "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8;\r\n".
            "Connection: close\r\n",
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "timeout" => (float)30.0,
        "content" => $strRequestXML,
    ),
    "ssl"=>array(
        "allow_self_signed"=>true,
        "verify_peer"=>false,
    ),
);

file_get_contents("https://somedomain:2000/abc/", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

.

Has anyone encountered this with file_get_contents? **Any ideas how to debug?**

Comment: Did you try setting `allow_self_signed` to false?

Comment: Just tried it, same error.

Comment: Why not just use cURL?

Comment: Yeah, cURL seems to be the best bet. A few google searches shows me that others have had the same problem without being able to solve it. They all fell back on cURL.

Comment: What happens if you use `'false'` string instead of `false` boolean?

Comment: @sjdaws Well, if the internal code casts to boolean, then I would be passing `true` to the function. And I tried with `true`, same behaviour.

Comment: Agree but `verify_peer` defaults to false so I don't understand why you're setting it at all. It's worth a try.

Comment: Very late to this question but you can also try `'verify_peer_name'=>false`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed `verify_peer_name`. If you set that to false as well, the request works:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "http" => array(
        "method" => "POST",
        "header" => 
            "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8;\r\n".
            "Connection: close\r\n",
        "ignore_errors" => true,
        "timeout" => (float)30.0,
        "content" => $strRequestXML,
    ),
    "ssl"=>array(
        "allow_self_signed"=>true,
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);

file_get_contents("https://somedomain:2000/abc/", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Answer (score 1):

dont' know if this will actually help, but do try removing the `SSL` options from your option array.

The reason behind this:
according to http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php , `verify_peer` is `false` by default.

`allow_self_signed` REQUIRES `verify_peer`, and is `false` by default.

From the above, I gather that `allow_self_signed` probably overrides your setting for `verify_peer`.

So please try without any option for `SSL`, or without the `allow_self_signed`, and let us know if that helped any.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to debug this with [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) -- you might get a better idea of what goes wrong, you should see which SSL error occurs.

Comment: You're getting "Connection reset by peer", which means it doesn't neccessarily hang up. I'm guessing if the client and server can't agree on which SSL handshake version to use, you'd get this error.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://somedomain/abc/", 2000 , $ErrNo, $ErrString, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Error No : $ErrNo - $ErrString <br />\n";
} else {
    $out  = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: somedomain \r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8;\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```

if you don't get error , i think problem (with file_get_contents) is form client php configuration otherwise from server configuration.

Comment: Ok, fsockopen worked. However, there is nothing wrong with the PHP configuration. It works just fine with many other HTTPS self signed SSL certificates.

Answer (score -1):

only install this

```
yum install ca-certificates.noarch
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!