# The 'file_get_contents()' is not working on local Laravel/PHP environment

Tags: php, macos, laravel-4, openssl

I have a Laravel (php) application running on a unix server, and now when I tried to pull it to my local environment (Mac OX 10.11) I encounter the following error:

```
file_get_contents(): SSL: Connection reset by peer
```

I've searched here, and saw that many users in the community suggest to check the 'php.ini' file and make sure that

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

`extension=php_openssl.dll` is enabled.

And so I modified the file accordingly - yet the problem persists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents ignoring verify\_peer=>false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076819/file-get-contents-ignoring-verify-peer-false)

Comment: Thanks, I don't believe this is a duplication, my case present other variables to take into account (also in the link the problem was not solved elegantly, but by using a different function..)

Comment: Provide your configuration; especially the SSL part. The reset could be due to enabling SSLv3 and such. Also, Let's Encrypt probably did *not* sign a certificate for ***`localhost`*** or ***`127.0.0.1`***, so we need to see the certificate you are using for the site, including the SubjectAltNames. We also need to know exactly how you are connecting to the site since hostnames matter.

Comment: I'm not using 'Let's Encrypt' but COMODO. I think this is Mac issue, since my colleagues using linux are able to run the software on their local host