# How to make a request to over HTTPS via file_get_contents() without openssl by not verifying ssl?

Tags: php, ssl, https, file-get-contents

I am making an application that deals with postbacks, and I wanted to make it so it would be able to postback to domains with `https://` even if the person who is using the app doesn't have the `openssl` php extension. (It would warn them that their postbacks would be made non securely.)

I turned off `openssl` and tried the following, but it is giving me an error that I do not have https wrapper.

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
  "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);
echo file_get_contents('https://httpbin.org/get?test=test', true, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions) );
```

Is it possible to make this request with `file_get_contents`?

Comment: possible duplicate [file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)

Comment: I came across this question previously and as you can see my code directly matches the accepted answer.

Comment: No it does not match the accepted answer there the second param was set to `false` but in your answer is `true`

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately neither would work in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://somedomain/abc/", 2000 , $ErrNo, $ErrString, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Error No : $ErrNo - $ErrString <br />\n";
} else {
    $out  = "POST / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: somedomain \r\n";
    $out .= "Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8;\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

I have research file_get_contents with **--no-check-certificate**

readmore here [file_get_contents ignoring verify_peer=>false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076819/file-get-contents-ignoring-verify-peer-false)